# How to use IntelliSense inside /// comments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Assume we have the following simple construct:

```
/// <summary>
/// The Foo class.
/// </summary>
class Foo { }

/// <summary>
/// I can store a [INTELLISENSE HERE to insert Foo] object.
/// </summary>
class Bar
{
    public Foo foo;
}
```

Is there a way to insert a reference to `Foo` in the comments of class `Bar` using built-in IntelliSense? Or is there a free Visual Studio 2010 plugin which provides me that behavior?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I don't want to know, which XML tags VS provides. I want to know how to insert the word `Foo` using intellisense (e.g. by pressing `CTRL+SPACE` for auto-completion) and not by typing it manually. Hope the question now is clear enough...

Comment: I believe resharper will do this.

Comment: Intellisense works if you type one of the XML documentation comments.. such as `<seealso cref="Fo" />` .. unless that's Resharper doing it for me.. :/

Comment: If you're looking to add a comment about the `Bar.Foo`, just put the comment over the property or field declaration.

Comment: @DanielA.White Is there a free alternative to Resharper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReSharper supports working with the XML comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use < paramref > parameter inside XML

Comment: I think you mean `<see>`.

Comment: That's no answer to my question. I want to know how to use IntelliSense in the VS editor to insert a reference to `Foo` without typing `Foo` manually.